# Have internet connection but can't ping External sites

Tags: network-manager, ping

I have an Internet connection and can browse, but I can't ping the google DNS,

```
ping 8.8.8.8
```

nor can I `ping google.com`

Any ideas why this might occur?

Comment: Can you ping other external sites/IPs ?

Comment: Yeah, I can ping my router, which my computer is not a member of.

Comment: I mean can you ping e.g. `104.16.18.44` or `askubuntu.com` ?

Comment: No I am not able to.

Comment: check my answer please.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your Firewall is configured to block all ICMP packets. As a result you cannot send ICMP echo request packets to external networks.

To resolve this issue you need to contact the network administrator and request that they disable this firewall rule.

Comment: Thank you. I am also having an issue connecting to my VPN to a router hosting a sub-network under the same network as my computer. Is the reason the same reason why I can't ping?

Comment: Might be..a rule can be added for that too..further diagnosis needed for that......your network administrator can confirm you..

Comment: what will the network administrator do?